# Is there a word that encompasses the outputs of different businesses?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing some copy for my web design business and am currently writing the home page headline. I want it to be related to “building a showcase for my clients”. The difficulty is that my clients span a variety of industries.

For example, the following text would be appropriate for a company who sell retail products:

“Showcase your products”

Whereas a university may wish to “showcase their courses”. A research institution may wish to “showcase their research”. Etc.

Is there a collective word that can encompass each of these? I was thinking “showcase your organisational outputs” but it doesn’t exactly roll off the tongue!

Comment: Showcase your interests and activities. £10,000 please.

Comment: Unable to stretch to that unfortunately. Have an upvote though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for free copy?? -.-

Something like...

> “Showcase your products or services”

...would include university offerings. Could use underscores...

> “Showcase your ______ "

Super businessy jargon "deliverable" or "widget" would apply to darn near anything, but that would be less user friendly.

Comment: "offerings" itself is a good collective word to use - as in products and offerings.

Comment: @user22542 yes!

Comment: I’ve decided to create industry specific landing pages in order to make the copy more tailored but I’ve marked as answer because I think yours is as close as I’m going to get. Thanks.